# How to disable Google Drive's own "delete?" dialogue?

Tags: google-drive

I recently installed Google Drive on my Windows 7 PC to move and delete some files with better interface (through Windows Explorer) by dragging files between folders and mass-deleting, and my Windows 7 already asks me once if I'm sure about deleting those files, but it doesn't prevent Google Drive from popping up its own prompt asking the same question. And there isn't a checkbox for disabling that in Google Drive's settings window. How do I disable Google Drive's own delete prompt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at this entry.

it worked for me.

http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/dP44DklCxoc

Specifically this answer: http://productforums.google.com/d/msg/drive/dP44DklCxoc/7c1x_hfqdnsJ

Here's a copy of the answer:

> Frank_P (Google employee):
>
> Hi folks,
>   We'll work on adding a way to disable this dialog for good. In the meantime, it can be disabled with a command line option. You'll have to start Drive manually for this to work.
>
> On Windows:
>   Start -> type "cmd.exe" and hit Enter
>   In the command window, enter this exactly:
>   `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Drive\googledrivesync.exe" --noshow_confirmation_dialog_on_delete`
>
> On Mac:
>   Run the Terminal app (in /Applications/Utilitites)
>   In the terminal window, enter this exactly:
>   `/Applications/Google\ Drive.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Drive --noshow_confirmation_dialog_on_delete`

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! To stop link rot, we prefer that our user's write up an answer here and post it on this site. Citing your sources is fine, but please take the time to create at least a quick summary of the solution when you create an answer.

Comment: Okay, this worked. Now instead there is a taskbar popup bubble saying the files I just deleted were moved to trash on Google Drive. Much less annoying.

Comment: not work on #macos -- ERROR: Unknown command line flag 'noshow_confirmation_dialog_on_delete'

Answer (score 0):

The answer above starts Drive manually with a flag provided by a Google employee. This answer uses a batch file and the windows Startup folder to automate the process.

The first step is to find the Startup folder for the user who wants to automatically start Drive. It should be somewhere around here:

```
C:\Users\[that_user's_name]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

The second step is to create a file in that folder called `[whatever_makes_sense_to_you].bat` and using notepad insert in it the following line:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Drive\googledrivesync.exe" --noshow_confirmation_dialog_on_delete
```

You should test it, and if it rejects the path you can go to your own Drive folder and right click to put a shortcut to it on the desktop. Then you can right click that shortcut and click properties, and then replace the path in the .bat file with the path specified by the shortcut.

Now all should be well and good, and since the .bat file is in the Startup folder, it will run every time that user starts a new session on the computer.

Comment: Actually you can even modify the startup link to the file to include the `--noshow...` parameter, so there's no need for an unnecessary step like running a bat file.

Answer (score -1):

Google has since changed the name of Drive and the structure of the folders. With a bit of trial and error this did the trick

/Applications/Backup\ and\ Sync.app/Contents/MacOS/Backup\ and\ Sync --noshow_confirmation_dialog_on_delete

BBL
Jan 2018

Comment: This might be applicable to a person with the question today, but when the author asked the question, these directories wouldn't have existed.

Comment: I just updating the directory. But if you dont like it I have better use for my time.

Comment: Author was also using Windows not MacOS.

Comment: Providing up-to-date answer is OK since it will be useful. It "was useful" will not be relevant, fast. Same goes with providing answer to different OS--it will be useful for the community at large.